# Redirects of only some pages from parent company site to new website

Tags: 301-redirect, link-juice

We have have recently split from our parent company and are now an independent company with a brand new website.

The parent company has a very authorative site and (being new) we have none. We are getting our pages on the parent company site redirected to our new website. Product pages are getting a direct 301, but some of the higher level pages will have some explanatory text and then a link to click to the new website.

The parent wants to have all our existing high-level menu items redirected to a single page that explains that we are now independent and includes a selection of links to our new (high-level) pages. (basically 20 pages -> 1 page -> 20 links).

We wanted each high level page to have an individual description of the de-merger, and a link directly to the corresponding page on our site (1 page -> 1 link).

Does anyone know which of these methods would give us the best link juice from the parent company site?

Hope that is clear.

Comment: From a user perspective it would be best to be able to get to the correct page easily, even if it requires a click.   If the message to show is at `/message.html` it might be nice to have it parametrized like `/message.html?page=/foo.html` so that it shows the message and then only has one link to click on which is the link for the page the user wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link juice degrades with how far away the link is from the homepage and other important pages on the site.

If a homepage links to another site it passes partial juice.

If a homepage links to an internal page that links to a site the juice is degraded between the homepage to the internal page, and then degraded again from the internal page to the site.

It is much better for your SEO to have links coming directly from the parent site on all of their major pages. If the link is coming from a a subpage the link juice degrades substantially.

Perhaps even more important is page authority. If the parent site is linking directly to you from pages that are ranking on Google, these carry tremendous link juice. If instead the parent site is going to link to a subsidiary-page.html that talks about your site, and then links to you, these pages are worth far less. The subsidiary-page.html has very low page authority. It's not currently ranking on Google for any keywords, and it probably never will rank for much because it doesn't have a whole lot of important content on it. It's just a page that links to your site.

If you're linked to from subsidiary-page.html, you've been indirectly linked to from a high authority domain, but from a page with low page authority. Not the greatest.

If you're linked to from many pages that are ranking on Google, you've been directly linked to from a high authority domain and linked to by many high authority pages. Great!

Answer (score 1):

The best approach from an SEO perspective is 1 page -> 1 link.

Nonetheless the best solution would be a **301 redirect one to one** (without the middle page/link) and showing in the final page a small content-popup (similar to cookie consent notice) informing about the changes.